# Has Wolverine's apparent middle-agedness been explained?

Tags: marvel, powers, wolverine

Given his recuperative ability, why would he show any signs of age but rather have reached, say, 25 and then looked this way forever?
And given that he aged to apparent middle age, is there any indication that this process might continue, however slowly?

Comment: [Old Man Logan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Man_Logan)

Comment: Pretty sure all we know is that Wolverine's healing factor greatly slows his aging, but doesn't stop it entirely; thus with sufficient passage of time, he will look increasingly old. If you're looking for a more detailed, pseudoscientific explanation as to why his healing factor doesn't effectively stop his aging altogether, or slow it down even more than it does, you're unlikely to get it, as comics tend not to go into much detail regarding how various super powers actually work.

Comment: @LogicDictates: I am looking forward to a future where pseudoscience advances beyond our current frontiers. It may require some pseudoscientists who are genetically engineered to become super geniuses. Or something.

Comment: Not having read the comics, and going by just the movie, I was under the impression that his healing factor was not working as well as it had when he was younger, thus he takes longer to heal injuries, and his slowdown of the aging process is reduced, so that he IS getting older quicker (but probably still slower than a normal human.)

Comment: I think, for one, he looks pretty good for a man of 190.

Comment: I'm sure I read a comic once where it was speculated that if Logan had lived a non-violent, simply normal life, his healing factor would make him effectively immortal.  But the brutal damage he suffers have strained the little cellular engines to the max too often and the strain is showing.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: In maybe 1970, National Geographic of all serious magazines had a lengthy article about super-super centenarians from Soviet Georgia iirc and I think one was supposed to have been born before the War of 1812 -- I think the oldest guy was 170 maybe older and still cut his own firewood and rode a horse. Of course, total BS but NG thought it was real and so did millions of readers, presumably.

Answer (score 6):

Wolverine's healing factor *slows* the effect of aging while keeping his body in peak physical condition. It doesn't stop him from aging entirely. From *Wolverine: Weapon X Files*:

[image: Wolverine: Weapon X Files]

This is most noticeable in media set in the far future (like *Old Man Logan* or the movie *Logan*) where Wolverine has visibly aged.

[image]

One way to think of it is to pretend that Wolverine's lifespan is now 300 rather than the ~100 of the average human. In that case, Wolverine *is* middle-aged give or take a few decades. The artists who depict him as somewhat younger might instead say his lifespan is 400, and he is therefore closer to 30 in Wolverine Years.

Comment: seems if u can regenerate from just a head or whatever he does, not ageing ought to be easy.

Comment: @releseabe - It's not clear that Wolverine is capable of regrowing his body from just a head, and the evidence suggests that he can't under normal conditions. There's an often-cited issue where he regrew his flesh from a skeleton, but something frequently overlooked is that he had an arrangement with the Angel of Death at the time, which enabled his soul to leave the realm of dead and return to his body whenever he'd been mortally wounded. That arrangement ended not long afterwards, so on paper at least, he can no longer recover from injuries that serious.

Comment: @LogicDictates: Right, Angel of Death -- all is clear now.